# Django apache configuration with mod_wsgi module

Tags: python, django, apache

From [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/path/to/venv python-path=/path/to/mysite.com
WSGIProcessGroup example.com
```

where does 'python-home' point to ?
where does 'python-path' point to ?
where does 'example.com' point to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-home` is the path of the virtual env

`python-path` is your project directory (the one containing `manage.py`).

`example.com` is simply a unique name to identify your daemon process.

Comment: So if i do not have a virtual environment, should I not include 'python-home' line ? Or is there some other declaration to be included ??